# Querying multiple table to get specific data with Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am quite new to Laravel 4 and its great Eloquent ORM. I have four tables such as :

```
Sector          (iSectorCode);
MailingSector   (iSectorCode, iMailingCode);
Mailing         (iMailingCode);
MailingLanguages(iMailingCode, sTranslation);
```

I have the sector id, and I want to get all Mailings associated. But I also need to reach the MailingLanguages table containing the content translations for a specific Mailing.

So for now I can get all Mailings for a specific sector doing :

```
Sector::find($iSectorCode)->mailings()->get()->toArray();
```

But doing `Sector::find($iFormSectorCode)->mailings()->mailingsLanguages()->get()->toArray();` don't work even if the relation between Mailing and MailingLanguages is defined :

```
public function mailingsLanguages(){
    return $this->hasMany('MailingLanguage','iMailingCode');
}
```

So I don't know how to get all translations for a specific Mailing, for a specific Sector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing that you've setup relationships between all of the tables, you can request that they be grabbed with the initial request.

```
$sector = Sector::with('mailings', 'mailings.languages')->find($iSectorCode);
```

This will create a nice join that will include related records for `Mailing`, then their related records for `MailingLanguage`, as well as the requested `Sector`.

The above example does assume that `Sector` has a relationship called `mailings` and that `Mailing` has a relationship called `languages`.

You could also load them in after the fact.

```
$sector = Sector::find($iSectorCode);
$sector->load(['mailings', 'mailings.languages']);
```

I would recommend making use of the `findOrFail` method that laravel provides.

```
try {
    $sector = Sector::with(['mailings', 'mailings.langauges'])
        ->findOrFail($iSectorCode);
} catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    // do something here
}
```

This saves having to check whether `$sector` returned anything, as an exception will be thrown.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a side note, when checking for the `ModelNotFoundException`, remember to include it using `use` or provide its fully qualified namespace address, otherwise it won't catch properly in some situations.